Web.Config Redirect for Azure.Core not working as expected
I have a Microsoft Web Site project (different than a Web Application) that has version 1.20.0.0 of Azure.Core.dll as an assembly in the project.  However, a .cs file in the project is calling for version 1.15.0.0.  This is the error I get:
Could not load file or assembly 'Azure.Core, Version=1.15.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I included a binding redirect in my web.config file to ensure that the correct version will always be hit, formatted like so:
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Azure.Core" publicKeyToken="92742159e12e44c8" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.20.0.0" newVersion="1.20.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>

I would expect this to fix the issue but instead I still recieve the error.
Attempting to include shared assemblies from a similar project that works also did not produce the result that I wanted.
Unfortunately, I can't be more specific than this because the code isn't mine to post.  I'm also not able to change it to a different type of project, again because it isn't mine to change.
EDIT: It was suggested that I unload my project, but I don't see the option on my context menu, as illustrated by the image.


What is the version of your App?

Please share your .csproj file.

The project I'm working with doesn't have one, it's a much older Website Project.

Right click on the solution folder => Unload the project, you can see the file.

I can't seem to find the option to unload.   I tried to right-click on the project but I did not see an unload option.

Can you please share the screenshot of the folder n right click

I added it to the question

I don't know how to determine this for a Website project.  This is not an application project.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
